# JavaScript/ECMAscript 6 classes organization

Tags: javascript, object-oriented, ecmascript-6

I have been trying to wrap my head around all the new options in ECMAscript 6 and to do this I tried to develop a simple setup which would allow me to place absolutely positioned `<div>`s on the page.

**main.js:**

```
import {Screen} from './objects/screen';
import {Position} from './objects/position';

var welcomeScreen = new Screen("Hello World");
welcomeScreen.title = "Hello World2";
welcomeScreen.position = new Position(100,100);
//Make sure the following does work if you have any advices, because there is a simple mistake which breaks this:
console.log(welcomeScreen.position.x);

var secondScreen = new Screen("Second screen", new Position(200,200));
```

**objects/baseobject.js:**

```
export class BaseObject{
    on(eventname,func){
        if(typeof this.listeners == "undefined"){
            this.listeners = {};
        }
        if(typeof this.listeners[eventname] == "undefined"){
            this.listeners[eventname] = [];
        }
        this.listeners[eventname].push(func);
        return this;
    }
    trigger(eventname){
        if(this.listeners && this.listeners[eventname]){
            for(let func of this.listeners[eventname]){
                func.call(this);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**objects/screen.js:**

```
import {BaseObject} from './baseobject';
// private properties:
var pp = {
    position: Symbol(),
    title: Symbol()
};
export class Screen extends BaseObject{
    constructor(title,position = new Position(0,0)){
        this.element = document.createElement("div");
        this.element.classList.add("screen");
        this.title = title;
        this.position = position;
        document.body.appendChild(this.element);
    }
    reposition(){
        this.element.style.left = this.position.x + "px";
        this.element.style.top = this.position.y + "px";
    }
    set position(position){
        var that = this;
        this[pp.position] = position;
        this[pp.position].on("positionchange",function(){
            that.reposition();
        }).trigger("positionchange");
    }
    get position(){
        return this[pp.position];
    }
    set title(value){
        this[pp.title] = value;
        this.element.textContent = value;
    }
    get title(){
        return this[pp.title];
    }
}
```

**objects/position.js:**

```
import {BaseObject} from './baseobject';
// private properties:
var pp = {
    x: Symbol(),
    y: Symbol()
};
export class Position extends BaseObject{
    constructor(x,y){
        this[pp.x]=x;
        this[pp.y]=y;
    }
    set x(value){
        this[pp.x]=x;
        super.trigger("positionchange");
    }
    get x(){
        return this[pp.x];
    }
    set y(value){
        this[pp.y]=y;
        super.trigger("positionchange");
    }
    get y(){
        return this[pp.y];
    }
}
```

You can transpile ES6 to ES3 (I think it is 3) using [(Google) Traceur](https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler).

**Points of interest:**

- Are there nice ES6 language features I am forgetting?
- Is there a nicer way to handle the 'set triggers' (`->` private property construction)?
- Should I be using modules? Combine classes into the same files? etc.

Comment: Traceur does not support private in class bodies.. https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler/issues/57 That's a bit of a let down.

Comment: Have been reading the spec now for the last half hour and for the life of me, I can't figure out how private properties are 'supposed' to work (regardless of Traceur).

Comment: I looked at http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:classes#class_body -> check out the constructor.

Comment: That one is old and superseded by http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=strawman:maximally_minimal_classes

Comment: And yeah, I would have loved it if they could have agreed on that one. I thought you were talking about the `new Name()` stuff which I can't figure out.

Comment: Eh, I do not like some aspects of EC6 at all..

Comment: You are right indeed, but on the other hand, it's quite rare for companies of that magnitude trying to work together on something they can all agree on. So if they can agree on this then hopefully step by step we will not make any stupid mistakes (like so many have been made in the past already).

Comment: One point: now we have `const` and `let` it's easier to just ditch `var` completely. `var` behaves differently to `let` in terms of destructuring, hoisting, scoping, and redeclaration of existing variables, so it can be confusing to use both `var` and `let` at the same time.

Comment: Also `Object.assign(this, { foo, bar, baz: qux })` is shorter than `this.foo = foo; this.bar = bar; this.baz = qux`.

Comment: @gcampbell As far as `Object.assign` goes, do you actually believe it's clearer than just writing it out? I don't think programmers should ever care for the length of code, it's all about clarity (and oftenshorter code is clearer, as `Let the variable with the name x be 5` is a whole lot harder to parse visually than `let x = 5`)

Comment: @DavidMulder I think it's a matter of getting used to the pattern, so when you see `Object.assign(this, {})` you know what it means. What I do is: if you're in a `constructor`, then you can use Object.assign to set many (say, 5 or more) properties on `this`. If you only have a couple of things to assign, `this.x = x; this.y = y` is shorter and definitely easier to understand.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Most interesting,

- In `BaseObject`, you should really have a constructor that builds `this.listeners`, it would make your code much cleaner afterwards
- I am not sure why your listeners are not private in `BaseObject` ?
- I am not sure what is more important to you, learn EC6 or position divs efficiently, if the latter is more important, than this code is massive overkill ;)

If you want to avoid having a constructor for `BaseObject`, then I would re-write `on` like this:

```
on(eventname,func){
    this.listeners = this.listeners || [];
    this.listeners[eventname] = this.listeners[eventname] || [];
    this.listeners[eventname].push(func);
    return this;
}
```

Comment: To point 1 I did this because this way a user doesn't need to call the super constructor on each and every object he constructs. To point 2, you are absolutely right, I forgot entirely. And lastly to point 3: It is to learn EC6 whilst making a mobile app framework slowly (this was just me trying to figure out the setup).

Comment: Great suggestion btw@on :D

Answer (score 8):

So, going to 'answer' my own question here with a nice thing I discovered since then. Might expand my answer if I discover more stuff.

In ECMAscript 6 rather than

```
var that = this;
something.on("positionchange",function(){
     that.reposition();
});
```

You can do

```
something.on("positionchange",() => {
     this.reposition();
});
```

As the `this` scope doesn't change.

Comment: It's exciting though? Already with the latest additions I have stopped using typical javascript libraries for most my projects and with ES6 I can get rid of a couple I occasionally use again :D